# Jarsigner issue with jre/lib/ext removal

Tags: java, java-9, jarsigner

According to this article : https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/planning-safe-removal-of-under-used-endorsed-extension-directories

the jre/lib/ext removed in Java 9.

My problem is that I am using Jarsigner which in previous Java versions found my provider jar in the jre/lib/ext folder.

```
jarsigner -tsa timestamp.digicert.com -verbose -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 
      -storepass null -providername <MY_PROVIDER_NAME> <JAR_FILE> <CERTIFICATE_NAME>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Isn't the `<JAR_FILE>` enough to specify the jar to be signed. How does the `jre/lib/ext` removal impact this?

Comment: The  <JAR_FILE> is the JAR file to be signed. In jre/lib/ext i put my Java 
security provider JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally succeeded to resolve this issue, based on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/howtoimplaprovider.htm#JSSEC-GUID-7C304A79-6D0B-438B-A02E-51648C909876

Need to do the following (Only specifying what is new for Java9) :

Follow step 4 and add a module declaration:

```
module com.foo.MyProvider {
    provides java.security.Provider with p.MyProvider;
    requires java.security.jgss;
}
```

When running the Jarsigner run with with module–path:

```
jarsigner -J--module-path -J<PATH_TO_PROVIDER_JAR> -J--add-modules -J<MODULE_NAME>
-tsa timestamp.digicert.com -verbose -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -storepass null -providername <MY_PROVIDER_NAME> <JAR_FILE> <CERTIFICATE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [changes to the installed JDK/JRE image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-D867DCCC-CEB5-4AFA-9D11-9C62B7A3FAB1) brings along runtime images which consists of directories including -

> **conf** — contains .properties, .policy, and other kinds of files
>   intended to be edited by developers, deployers, and end users. These
>   files were formerly found in the lib directory or its subdirectories.

---

The `java.security` file within JDK9 (located under `.../Home/conf/security`) lists out the SunPKCS11 provider amongst the list of default providers

```
security.provider.13=SunPKCS11
```

*[#SunPKCS11 Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm#JSSEC-GUID-97F1E537-CB59-4C7F-AB6B-05D4DBD69AC0)* under the reference guide details out how to add provider which is present in the [`jdk.crypto.cryptoki`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk.crypto.cryptoki-summary.html) module of the JDK.

So, ideally there shouldn't be a need to configure path to the `sunpkcs11` provider in Java9 as well.

---

To add and example of how providers are bundled into modules, to it from the [JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220)

> Security-policy files and other uses of the CodeSource API can use jrt
>   URLs to name specific modules for the purpose of granting permissions.
>   The elliptic-curve cryptography provider, e.g., can now be identified
>   by the jrt URL
>
> ```
> jrt:/jdk.crypto.ec
> ```
>
> Other modules that are currently granted all
>   permissions but do not actually require them can trivially be
>   de-privileged, i.e., given precisely the permissions they require.